# Is a has_many :through relationship the right way to model this data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, data-modeling

I have a `Client` model that needs each client instance to own and create multiple addresses, email_ids, phone_numbers. A simple `has_many` relationship would not allow me to scale I presume so I thought I should go for a `has_many :through` relationship

I want to use a has_many :through relationship

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile
  has_many :addresses, :through => :profile
  has_many :emails, :through => :profile
  has_many :phonenumbers, :through => :profile
end

class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client
  has_many :addresses
  has_many :emailids
  has_many :phonenumbers
end

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :profile
end

class EmailId < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :profile
end

class PhoneNumber < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :profile
end
```

Will I then be able to execute queries like:

`client.phonenumbers` `client.create_phonenumbers` etc?

Or should I just stick to has_many belongs_to and put address, email_id and phone_number in the profile relationship and then say client `has_many` profiles? That doesn't sound right to me. Are there any benefits to the rich association that I have outlined above?

Answer (score 0):

I think it seems to be fine stick with the has_many :through. Because we don't need to put an extra relationship between client and other tables i.e addresses etc and also an extra column client_id in those tables. only putting profile id will do the same.

Comment: you mean just a has_many instead of a has_many :through - correct?